# Flex 4 Inline Item Editor Wiping Out Data

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

In this app that has an inline item editor, if you click on a location cell then press tab, the value in the location cell is wiped out.

focusOut doesn't work, nor could I get this to work in DataGrid itemEditEnding etc.

See this Flex forums post, because posting code here rots:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/778496

Answer (score 0):

The definition for the inline item editor needs this:

selectedItem="{data.location}"

instead of this:

prompt="{data.location}"

This is because the itemEditEnd event sets the newData property (deep within the code) to the value of selectedItem, so if you have only selected the cell and have not yet selected a value in the DropDownList, such as selecting the cell then immediately tabbing out, the value gets wiped out.